# Multiple XSLT files to single XSLT file for 2 different xml files

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<CONTACTS>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>Ford</FirstName>
        <LastName>Pasteur</LastName>
        <EMail>pasteur.ford@yahoo.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
        <LastName>Sully</LastName>
        <URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1000474277</URL>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>Colombo</FirstName>
        <LastName>Chao</LastName>
        <EMail>chao.colombo@liberto.it</EMail>
    </CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

I used below XSLT file for my fist version of xml output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CONTACT">
        <xsl:copy>
               <Customer-ID>
               <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/> 
               </Customer-ID>
              <xsl:copy-of select="FirstName|LastName|URL"/>
              <Facebook-ID>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="URL">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(URL,'?id=')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>

                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Facebook-ID>
            <EMAILS>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="EMail"/>
            </EMAILS>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EMail">
        <EMail> 
            <Type><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
                    substring-after(.,'@'),
                    '.')"/>
            </Type>
            <Value><xsl:value-of select="."/></Value>
        </EMail>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My first version of xml output from the above XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<CONTACTS>
    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>N65539</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>Ford</FirstName>
    <LastName>Pasteur</LastName>
    <EMAILS>
    <EMail>
    <Type>yahoo</Type>
    <Value>pasteur.ford@yahoo.com</Value>
    </EMail>
    </EMAILS>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>N65546</Customer-ID>
     <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
     <LastName>Sully</LastName>
     <URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1000474277</URL>
    <Facebook-ID>1000474277</Facebook-ID>
    <EMAILS/>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>N65553</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>Colombo</FirstName>
    <LastName>Chao</LastName>
    <EMAILS>
    <EMail>
    <Type>liberto</Type>
    <Value>chao.colombo@liberto.it</Value>
    </EMail>
    </EMAILS>
    </CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

This is my second XSLT file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CONTACT">
<xsl:copy>
    <Customer-ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="Customer-ID"/>
    </Customer-ID>

    <FirstName>
        <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
    </FirstName>

    <LastName>
        <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
    </LastName>

    <gmail>
            <xsl:value-of select="EMAILS/EMail[Type='gmail']/Value"/>
    </gmail>

    <yahoo>
            <xsl:value-of select="EMAILS/EMail[Type='yahoo']/Value"/>
    </yahoo>

    <liberto>
            <xsl:value-of select="EMAILS/EMail[Type='liberto']/Value"/>
    </liberto>

    <URL>
            <xsl:value-of select="URL"/>
    </URL>

    <Facebook-ID>
             <xsl:value-of select="Facebook-ID"/>
    </Facebook-ID>

      </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This is my final xml output from the 2nd XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<CONTACTS>

    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>N65539</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>Ford</FirstName>
    <LastName>Pasteur</LastName>
    <gmail/>
    <yahoo>pasteur.ford@yahoo.com</yahoo>
    <liberto/>
    <URL/>
    <Facebook-ID/>
    </CONTACT>

    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>N65546</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
    <LastName>Sully</LastName>
    <gmail/>
    <yahoo/>
    <liberto/>
    <URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1000474277</URL>
    <Facebook-ID>1000474277</Facebook-ID>
    </CONTACT>

    <CONTACT>
    <Customer-ID>N65553</Customer-ID>
    <FirstName>Colombo</FirstName>
    <LastName>Chao</LastName>
    <gmail/>
    <yahoo/>
    <liberto>chao.colombo@liberto.it</liberto>
    <URL/>
    <Facebook-ID/>
    </CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

How do I merge these two XSLT files as a single XSLT file to get my final XML output.

how do i proceed with this? because there are two different xml files of similar type.

I'm using Eclipse Hellios run as -->XSL transformation to see the output.

Comment: +1 for effort. I've adapted the two-phase example that you can find in [XSLT 2.0 rec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#d5e12785) to your use case XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `xsl:import` to reuse your XSLT files and then use the technique explained in the @Dimitre's answer as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">

    <xsl:import href="phase1.xsl"/>
    <xsl:import href="phase2.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="intermediate">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/CONTACTS/CONTACT" mode="phase1"/>
        </xsl:variable>
           <CONTACTS>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($intermediate)" 
         mode="phase2"/>
           </CONTACTS>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Where:

- phase1.xsl and phase2.xsl are your two xslt transforms
- transforms are slightly modified adding a `mode` to each template. For instance, phase1.xsl transform:

  ```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="phase1"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CONTACT" mode="phase1">
      <xsl:copy>
          <Customer-ID>
              <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/> 
          </Customer-ID>
          <xsl:copy-of select="FirstName|LastName|URL"/>
          <Facebook-ID>
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="URL">
                      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(URL,'?id=')"/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>

                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </Facebook-ID>
          <EMAILS>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="EMail" mode="phase1"/>
          </EMAILS>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EMail" mode="phase1">
      <EMail> 
          <Type><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
                  substring-after(.,'@'),
                  '.')"/>
          </Type>
          <Value><xsl:value-of select="."/></Value>
      </EMail>
  </xsl:template>
  ```

For phase2.xsl you will use `mode="phase2" obviously.

When the above conditions are satisfied, and the *merging* transform is applied to your first input XML, the following output is obtained:

```
<CONTACTS>
   <CONTACT>
      <Customer-ID>d0e2</Customer-ID>
      <FirstName>Ford</FirstName>
      <LastName>Pasteur</LastName>
      <gmail/>
      <yahoo>pasteur.ford@yahoo.com</yahoo>
      <liberto/>
      <URL/>
      <Facebook-ID/>
   </CONTACT>
   <CONTACT>
      <Customer-ID>d0e9</Customer-ID>
      <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
      <LastName>Sully</LastName>
      <gmail/>
      <yahoo/>
      <liberto/>
      <URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1000474277</URL>
      <Facebook-ID>1000474277</Facebook-ID>
   </CONTACT>
   <CONTACT>
      <Customer-ID>d0e16</Customer-ID>
      <FirstName>Colombo</FirstName>
      <LastName>Chao</LastName>
      <gmail/>
      <yahoo/>
      <liberto>chao.colombo@liberto.it</liberto>
      <URL/>
      <Facebook-ID/>
   </CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Performing a chain of transformations is used quite often in XSLT applications**, though doing this entirely in XSLT 1.0 requires the use of the vendor-specific `xxx:node-set()` function. In XSLT 2.0 no such extension is needed as the infamous RTF datatype is eliminated there.

**Here is an example** (too-simple to be meaningful, but illustrating completely how this is done):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:variable name="vPass1"
        select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"
        select="$vPass1/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[. mod 2 = 1]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select=". *2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<num>2</num>
<num>6</num>
<num>10</num>
<num>14</num>
<num>18</num>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **In the first step the XML document is transformed** and the result is defined as the value of the variable `$vrtfPass1`. This copies only the `num` elements that have odd value (not even).
2. **The `$vrtfPass1` variable, being of type RTF, is not directly usable for XPath expressions** so we convert it to a normal tree, using the EXSLT (implemented by most XSLT 1.0 processors) function `ext:node-set` and defining another variable -- `$vPass1` whose value is this tree.
3. **We now perform the second transformation in our chain of transformations** -- on the result of the first transformation, that is kept as the value of the variable `$vPass1`. Not to mess with the first-pass template, we specify that the new processing should be in a named mode, called "pass2". In this mode the value of any `num` element is multiplied by two.

**XSLT 2.0 solution** (no RTFs):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vPass1" >
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>
  </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"
        select="$vPass1/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[. mod 2 = 1]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select=". *2"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @karthik rangaraj: If I understand your question well, you are asking how to apply the second transformation on the result of the first transformation. In my answer I am showing this in an example that illustrates the technique. You can use the same technique to chain together your two transformations, or in general any two or more transformations. Read well the explanation.

Comment: Great technique. I have understood your technique and explanation. @empo: used your technique and everything works fine. Thank you for your technique.