# Process multiple XSLT files to single XSLT file for 2 different xml files, 1 XSLT file output will be input to 2 XSLT file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have a requirement where I have to process xml using 1st XSLT, on the result of this I have to run 2nd XSLT.

Same question is addressed already here by @Emiliano Poggi : [Multiple XSLT files to single XSLT file for 2 different xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720009/multiple-xslt-files-to-single-xslt-file-for-2-different-xml-files)

but in my case I am just transforming the small piece and copying everything as it is(using identity transform). when I use modes the text template match is coming as expected, but remaining is coming like text.

Here is my input xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<section>
  <a>a</a>
  <b>b</b>
  <c>
      <d>1</d>
      <d>2</d>
  </c>
  <f>f</f>
  <!-- some more tags are there -->
</section>
```

My xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"  mode="phase1"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="c" mode="phase1">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <generator>
        <xsl:iterate select="./d">
            <test>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </test>
        </xsl:iterate>
        </generator>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
   <a>a</a>
   <b>b</b>
   <c>
      <d>1</d>
      <d>2</d>
   </c>
   <generator>
      <test>1</test>
      <test>2</test>
   </generator>
   <f>f</f>
   <!-- some more tags are there -->
</section>
```

actual output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>ab<c>
      <d>1</d>
      <d>2</d>
   </c>
   <generator>
      <test>1</test>
      <test>2</test>
   </generator>f
</section>
```

can anyone please help me is there any way to solve this issue.
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42P4

Comment: I don't see why you need the mode at all. If you remove it, you will get the expected result: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42P4/1 What you have now applies templates in mode to ALL nodes in the input document - but you have a template only for `c` so the rest are handled by the built in templates.

Comment: If you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6720353/16632635 this comment, I'm also having same requirement. Here I'm importing(<xsl:import ..>) this xslt into main xslt and transforming.

Comment: Don't send me on errands.